# t test alternative when participants can belong to multiple groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, group-differences

Newbie here, so please excuse any faux pas.

I have participants who belong to different groups: A & B. However, a participant can also belong to both groups or to neither. Possibilities are A, B, A+B, or 0.

I would like to test for differences between the groups in a dependent variable. However, I do not know how to treat the A+B participants.

An extra point is that the dependent variable is a ratio, which I suspect might complicate matters. So it would also be useful to know whether there are methods that would or would not work for different types of DV.

Sorry if this is really obvious, but I have never had data like these before and haven't had any luck searching using keywords.

Comment: Just to be clear, membership in one of these four possible groupings is mutually exclusive for each participant, correct? In other words, each participant can belong to one and only one of the combinations. Please clarify how the DV's ratio is calculated.

Comment: DJohnson, thanks for the question. 

The participant (a person) chooses to assign themselves to a group. They can assign themselves to multiple groups, or none. As an example, a person might choose to join a football club, a golf club, both, or neither. The DV is derived from two physical measurements: one divided by the other.

Comment: Thx. Why wouldn't this fit a classic ANOVA model?

Comment: @DJohnson Yes, this is what David Ernst suggested. Seems obvious now he has said it. I guess I was blinded by the suspicion that it must be more complicated than it really is.

Comment: It wouldn't fit a classical ANOVA model because the same person in different groups violate independence.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks. So David’s answer below won’t work? When I read it it seemed to make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possibilities.

You could make it a two way ANOVA:

- A or notA
- B or notB

That would also allow you to look at interaction effects. You would need to put some thought into how many and which post-hoc tests you will need.

You could also go for a flat design and look at 4 distinct groups:

- A but not B
- B but not A
- neither
- both

If you also need to control for some other variables, which may be continuous, then a regression is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, David. This approach eluded me for some reason. As you can see above, Glen_b has suggested that the same person in different groups would violate independence. I am not sure if this is correct, but I am not expert enough to know if the independence rule applies in this case. Do you have an opinion?

Comment: I don't see where there would be a same person in different groups though. It's the same as if you had a factor male/female (A or notA) and another treatment/placebo (B or notB). That's done all the time as long as a single person cannot be male and female and/or treatment and placebo at the same time. You also don't have people who are simultaneously A *and* notA...

Comment: That's very clear. Much appreciated!